# Windbg: Is there any command to show me only the threads that belong to a certain library?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I know that exists command: ~*k which shows all threads and I know that exist command ~[id_thread]s which show the stack for id_thread. I want to see just threads that belong to a certain library loaded in windbg.

Comment: thread not belong to any module in strict sense. so no such info can be query for thread. but in more general sense - we can use thread entry point address as hint - which module create this thread and as result "owner" of thread. however if thread for instance created with `_beginthreadex` - even detect real entry point for thread became problematic. but if you can view stack trace in debugger - you can view - in which module thread begin execute

Comment: Problem is: threads don't belong to a library. They are not owned by anyone. You can abort any thread from any other thread. Do you want to know which threads currently execute code from a specific library?

Comment: yes, this is what I want

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg's scripting capabilities are limited when it comes to dealing with strings and searching. You need to invoke a shell. Maybe the following is sufficient for you:

```
~*e ? @$tid; .shell -ci "k" findstr "kernel32"
```

Therefore I suggest that you use the [PyKd WinDbg extension](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd-ext/-/wikis/Downloads). Note that you need a Python installation with the correct bitness and a `pip install pykd` for each bitness.

The quick and dirty way is to use `dbgCommand()` and parse the output. The better way is to use the [API](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/-/wikis/API%20Reference).

I'm not a PyKD expert, but something like this works for me:

```
import sys
print("Python version:", sys.version)
print("Script path: " + sys.argv[0])
   
from pykd import *
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: findlib <library>")
    exit(1)
    
lib = sys.argv[1]
try:
    offset = expr(lib)
except DbgException:
    print(f"{lib} is not a valid module")
    exit()
print(f"Finding {lib} at {offset:08x}")

modules = getModulesList()
for module in modules:
    if module.begin() == offset:
        begin = module.begin()
        end = module.end()


threads = getProcessThreads()
for thread in threads:
    setCurrentThread(thread)
    # print(f"Examining thread {thread:08x}")
    frames = getStack()  
    found = False    
    for frame in frames:
        try:
            # unfortunately findSymbol() hangs for me if no symbols are available
            # otherwise it would have been a much cleaner approach
            # and no messing with the module list
            # dll, method, offset = frame.findSymbol()
            if begin <= frame.ip < end:
                found = True                
        except SymbolException:
            pass
    if found:
       print(f"Found on thread with TEB {thread:08x}")
```

Usage in WinDbg:

```
.load <path_to_ext>\pykd
!py <path_to_script>\findlib kernel32
```